# Static CSS not being applied to django-allauth templates

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

My templates do not seem to be able to access static css files. The project using all-auth for authentication. My file structure is as follow:

```
    Project Folder   
      app 1 
      app 2 
      static
        css
          style.css 
       templates
         account
           login.html
           signup.html
          base.html
          home.html
```

`base.html` is as follow:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Shuffle</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='{% static "css/style.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="card">
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock %}
          </div> <!--card -->
    </body>
</html>
```

The rest of the templates extend from base.html. On inspecting the rendered page, all the html are correct but the styling is missing.

Edit:

Error is shown as:

```
    GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1665
```

Static directory in setting is set as:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
```

Comment: "but the styling is missing" What exactly happens? CSS file not found (error 404)? Is the full link to the CSS file the correct link?

Comment: @Ralf The error is shown as: "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1665

For static files the settings are:
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

Comment: are you using djangos `runserver` command with `DEBUG=True`? If not, how are you [serving your static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/)?

Comment: @ralf I am running with django's runserver and DEBUG=TRUE is set. I do have all-auth installed. Could that affect it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need to add the setting [`STATICFILES_DIRS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS).

You should have all 3 parts in your settings:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Comment: it works after the STATIC_ROOT file got removed and the STATICFILES_DIR got added as you suggested. Thank you so much for being so patient and helpful, Ralf! :) 
Seems I can't upvote here yet :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your folder is called `CSS` all uppercase, but in your template code (`<link href='{% static "css/style.css" %}' rel="stylesheet">`) you have folder name `css` in lowercase.

I also see that the folder `Static` has the first letter capitalized, but the settings code `STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` has the folder name as all lowercase.

Both of these have to match their counterparts, capitalization is important in this part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ralf but I just checked the folder and the folder is in lower case in my file and matches the link. The styling is still not being applied

Comment: sorry for the confusion. All my folder names are in lower case and all the files match. I have corrected the formatting in my question.